# Can I do a better Regex search with python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to find 8 digit numbers (sometimes with a space in between) in big text files.

I'm first testing whether 8 digit numbers exist first and then try to list them.

```
import re

test_str = '''
123456789123
1242232
'''

def searchfor8digits(input_string):
    regex = r'\d{8}|\d{4}\s\d{4}'
    matches = re.finditer(regex, input_string)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        matchNum = matchNum + 1
        print("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(
            matchNum=matchNum, match=match.group(),
            start=match.start(), end=match.end()))


def contains8digits(input_string):
    regex = r'\d{8}|\d{4}\s\d{4}'
    matches = re.finditer(regex, input_string)
    if matches:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if contains8digits(test_str):
        searchfor8digits(test_str)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Is there a better/more pythonic way to check if 8 digit numbers are present?

Also how can I test better if the input string is too big/long?

Comment: Better ? The way your doing it now `\d{8}|\d{4}\s\d{4}` is ok, something wrong with that ?

Comment: You don't have to over complicate things. Move that if into the other function.

Comment: a more efficient regex might be `r'\d{4}\s?\d{4}'`

Comment: Also, no need to do things twice. Use one function to create a list, return true or false.

Comment: If you plan to avoid matching 8-digit chunks inside longer digit chunks, add lookarounds, `(?<!\d)(?:\d{8}|\d{4}\s\d{4})(?!\d)`

Comment: how does lookarounds help with longer chunks? can you explain little more?

Comment: if its line delimited, no reason to use lookaround, just check for the delimiter (newline) or even better, use `$` and `^`